# Simple random generator script not working

Tags: php

I have this script but it's not working, not sure how to fix it, any tips please? all I get out the other end is the letter "t"

Thanks :)

```
<?php
$cachefile = './current_t_id';
$time = $id = null; // assume we have no cached quote
$change_every = 3600; // seconds
$pages = array(1 => 'text1-1.php', 2 => 'text1-2.php');

foreach($pages as $pagekey => $page){
    if($pagekey == $siteId){
        include($page);
    }
}

// if cached quote exists, load it
if(is_file($cachefile)) {
    list($time, $id) = explode(' ', file_get_contents($cachefile));
}

// if no cached quote or duration expired, change it
if(!$time || time() - $time > $change_every) {
    srand ((double) microtime() * 100000);
    $id = rand(0,count($page)-1);
    file_put_contents($cachefile, time().' '.$id); // update cache
}

// echo the quote, be it cached or freshly picked 
echo ($page[$id]);
?>
```

Comment: Hey Wrong move .. this is duplicate of your last post .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011620/random-quotes-script-on-a-timer  i don't that was a wise move

Comment: I've added the suggestions made in the last post and I can't get them to work together, so I'm asking for help, please do not accuse me of things before checking the facts please.

Comment: Whats the difference .. you should have just updated your question .. you did not even accept if the solution worked for you or not ...

Comment: The last post, I asked about adding a new feature, now I'm asking how to get those features to work together, because the script is broken. Very different questions

Comment: You are outputting `$page`, but the only place where you assign value to it is in `foreach($pages as $pagekey => $page)`, where `$page` gets assigned string values.

Comment: why is it not getting value from the array? should it be outputting $pages not $page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK am going to give you 3 different examples

Variables

```
$quotes = array (
        "hello",
        "baba",
        "luke" 
);


$pages = array(1 => 'text1-1.php', 2 => 'text1-2.php');
```

A. Using Random Quotes

```
// Using Ramdom Quptes
$key = array_rand ( $quotes );
echo $quotes [$key]; 
//Or
include($pages[$key]) ;
```

B. Using Robin

```
// Using Robin
$cacheFile = "robin.cache";
$robin = null;
$quotesID = intval ( file_get_contents ( $cacheFile ) );
$totalQuotes = count ( $quotes );

$key = ($quotesID < ($totalQuotes - 1)) ? $quotesID ++ : 1;
file_put_contents ( $cacheFile, $quotesID );

echo $quotes [$key];
//Or
include($pages[$key]) ;
```

Using Timer

```
// Using Timer

$cacheFile = "timer.cache";
$expiration = 3600;

$robin = null;
list($quotesID, $time) = explode(' ', file_get_contents($cacheFile));
$totalQuotes = count ( $quotes );

if($time < (time() - $expiration))
{
    $key = mt_rand(0,count($pages)-1);
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, time().' '.$id);
}
echo $quotes [$key];
//Or
include($pages[$key]) ;
```

I hope your issue can be resolved now

Thanks
:)

Comment: Okay, I'll pay around with this, Thank you :)

Comment: Good to know you have fixed the issue .

Comment: I apologise for our misunderstanding before. My bad